# How can I run WebDriver script using Ant?

Tags: ant, selenium-webdriver, junit4

I'm new to WebDriver. I have created data driven framework for Google calculator, Search, Sign in and sign up functionality with JUnit lib.

I want to run my script using Ant.

Below is the configuration for my environment:

OS: win8

Selenium-server-standalone-2.38.0.jar

Junit 4

Apache Ant 1.7

Please help.

Comment: Reading the basic documentation would have answered your question. http://ant.apache.org/manual/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you are aware of Ant you can run it through build.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to run it via ANT:

1. Check that you have ant installed in your system, properly. Open Command Prompt and type `ant`, if you have it installed perfectly it print in command prompt **`build.xml` doesn't exist** and/or **Build failed**

   But if none of above messages displayed you need follow below steps:
          1.1 Right Click **My Computer** icon and go to properties
          1.2 Go to **Advanced System Settings** >> **Advanced** tab >> click **Environment Variables** under **Start up and recovery**
   and create a new variable **ANT_HOME** and give ant directory path to it
          1.3 Edit **Path** variable and add ant's bin directory path to it (do not add/remove path already present in their)
   <>See pictures below to set it properly:
   [image: ANT_HOME]>
   [image: Path variable]
2. Once point one is done, go to your project's directory and open command prompt there (shift+right click will give option to open command prompt in working directory).
3. Now type ant "target name in your `build.xml`" example: **ant run**

Comment: Hi paul and venki, thanks for your reply. Do i need to make some changed in build file with above steps?

Comment: That's a separate question, need to see your `build.xml`, but if above answer has helped or is that what you were looking, accept it, so that other folks on SOF can get help.

Comment: Hi paul, You are right. My first question is solved due to above answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to know that you got your answer. Accept the answer, by clicking "check" mark.

Comment: Thanks for guidance paul. I was new to stack overflow. So didnt know how to accept the answer.

Comment: @paul: Your answer seems to be installation and configuration of ant. What's the content of build.xml file to execute the Selenium WebDriver tests?

Comment: @RiponAlWasim post a separate question and share a link with me here. Also post what have you tried. I'll be glad to help you out.

Comment: OK Paul. Thanks for you cooperation